# AT command for temperature

Tags: at-command

I am trying to connect a device over RS232 and communicate using AT commands, my understanding is that for example when dialling a number, I would use AT(make sure the device is ready to listen)D(dial command)037455773(example number). The device to which I am connecting has the capability of recording the temperature around it, but I cannot find the command in this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set

Is there more I need to learn before getting to that stage, and if so, could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance, Ed

Comment: A lot of modem chipsets have vendor specific AT commands so i think you need a data sheet for your particular device to solve this one.

Comment: More specifically, any modem chipset vendor that does *not* provide a manual for the AT commands the chip supports is a horrible one that you should never, never, ever use.